# Creating SlideShow using PHP and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Ok, i am trying to create a simple slideshow **but Not** automatic slideshow just like auto next slide **but** the user need to click next before it will go to next slide. 
So, ok, i have greater than 50 images and i want to display it by batch like the first 8 and the next 8 and the next 8 batch etc...

Example:
[image]

so the next second 8 batch will be toggle next on click of next(The orange Arrow). and then on back press the last show batch will be toggle back.

heres what i've done now..

from index.php(This only show the first 8 batch)

```
<div class="flowers-gallery-show">
        <ul class="ul-flowers">
            <li class="li-flowers">
                <div class="c-flowers">
                    <h1 class="flower-name">White Sympthay Box</h1>
                    <img src="images/new_flowers/1.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li-flowers">
                <div class="c-flowers">
                    <h1 class="flower-name">White Sympthay Box</h1>
                    <img src="images/new_flowers/2.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li-flowers">
                <div class="c-flowers">
                    <h1 class="flower-name">White Sympthay Box</h1>
                    <img src="images/new_flowers/3.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li-flowers">
                <div class="c-flowers">
                    <h1 class="flower-name">White Sympthay Box</h1>
                    <img src="images/new_flowers/4.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li-flowers">
                <div class="c-flowers">
                    <h1 class="flower-name">White Sympthay Box</h1>
                    <img src="images/new_flowers/1.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li-flowers">
                <div class="c-flowers">
                    <h1 class="flower-name">White Sympthay Box</h1>
                    <img src="images/new_flowers/2.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li-flowers">
                <div class="c-flowers">
                    <h1 class="flower-name">White Sympthay Box</h1>
                    <img src="images/new_flowers/3.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li-flowers">
                <div class="c-flowers">
                    <h1 class="flower-name">White Sympthay Box</h1>
                    <img src="images/new_flowers/4.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<!---The button--->
<div class="buttons-this">
        <span class="icon-prev" title="Back">
        </span>
        <span class="icon-next" title="Next">
        </span>
</div>
```

now, to show the next 8 batch and the other is unknown for me. 
and on my jquery, im stock with this code.

```
$('.icon-next').click(function(e){
        //To show the next 8 batch
});

$('.icon-back').click(function(e){
            //To show the last 8 batch
});
```

i know i can do this by querying the next 8 batch on button click via ajax but it will take sometimes to load the next 8 batch so what i want is load the first 8 batch and on page load i will query all the images so the page load and the NEXT click will be easy and fast. but i dont know how can i command to show the next 8 batch and the next 8 batch etc. and show the last 8 batch on button back.

any help for this problem? Thank you so much!!!
for some clarification please just ask me. thank you again!

Comment: You're attempting to do is jump the chasm with two leaps.  First, you must demonstrate the ability to fetch the information you need from the server and render it (regardless of paging).  Then, you can "slide" the views in and out (or left and right) as needed.  there are many things that can be done to optimize this of course - but you need the basics in place first.

Comment: can you give me reference for this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On page load you could add the remaining groups of eight in their own  blocks with the additional class of "hide" or some such which is set to display:none

your back and next functions would query which one of the .flowers-gallery-show children .ul-flowers is :visible. Then whether it is back or next, apply the "hide" class to the currently visible one and remove it from the appropriate one (before or after).

Utilizing something like:

```
var current = jQuery('.ul-flowers').is(':visible');
var next = current.next('.ul-flowers');
current.addClass('hide');
next.removeClass('hide');
```

.prev() should be useful in the other case.

You'll need to handle the last one visible case in the next function and the first one visible case in the back function but that is pretty easy.

Comment: Perhaps it would be simpler for you to use an off-the-shelf plugin like [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) which has options for exactly what you are tying to accomplish here.